# get price converted in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, currency

I use this code to change dinamically the price when the input field of quantity, change value.

```
// we are going to hook this on priority 31, so that it would display below add to cart button.
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_total_product_price', 31);

function woocommerce_total_product_price() {

global $woocommerce, $product;
$max = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wc_mmax_max', true);
$min = get_post_meta($product->id, '_wc_mmax_min', true);

echo sprintf('<div id="product_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>', __('Prezzo Prodotto :', 'woocommerce'), '<span class="price">' . $product->get_price() . '</span>');
echo sprintf('<div id="cart_total_price" style="margin-bottom:20px;display:none">%s %s</div>', __('Totale Carrello :', 'woocommerce'), '<span class="price">' . $product->get_price() . '</span>');

$moltiplicazione_prodotto = $product->get_price() * $max;
$moltiplicazione_prodotto = number_format($moltiplicazione_prodotto, 2, '.', '');
echo sprintf('<div id="prodotti_quantity" style="margin-bottom:20px;">%s %s</div>', __('Prezzo Prodotto :', 'woocommerce'), '<span class="price">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $moltiplicazione_prodotto . '</span>');
?>
<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    var price = <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
            current_cart_total = <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total; ?>,
            currency = '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>';

    var quantita_iniziale = $('[name=quantity]').val();
    $('#prodotti_quantity').html(this.value);

    console.log("quantita iniziale", this.value);

    $('[name=quantity]').change(function () {
        if (!(this.value < 1)) {

            var product_total = parseFloat(price * this.value),
            cart_total = parseFloat(product_total + current_cart_total);

            $('#product_total_price .price').html(currency + product_total.toFixed(2));
            $('#cart_total_price .price').html(currency + cart_total.toFixed(2));
            if(this.value){
            $('#prodotti_quantity').html(this.value).hide();  
            }


        }
        $('#product_total_price,#cart_total_price').toggle(!(this.value <= 1));
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

It works, but don't replace the price of current currency.
If I change the currency in the product information the price change correct ( i use the plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/ ), but in my code not.

here some screenshot to understand :

in Euro Works :

http://prnt.sc/e9hf8n

If I change the currency the price is correctly converted in product, but in total of my code the total is wrong :

http://prnt.sc/e9hfh3

thanks for help